# How to switch user in ansible for entire sections?

Tags: python, ansible

I am fully aware about the `become_user` functionality in Ansible but there is something that I don't really get: how to *easily* perform actions as different users without having to specify the user for each of them.

It seems to be a real pain to add the become for every task, I am looking for a way to switch current user for multiple tasks.

Having to create new task files for each "block" would make the entire deployment logic quite hard to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There only are two options: Includes or blocks.

Includes are the only option in Ansible 1:

```
- include: run_as_user_x.yml
  become: true
  become_user: x
```

In Ansible 2 the [blocks](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_blocks.html) concept has been introduced:

```
- block:
    - some task
    - another task
    - task n
  become: true
  become_user: x
```